# How can I show notifications over the screen on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, notifications

Please allow me show you this example on Mailchimp's website:

[image]

[image]

See these notifications over the screen?

I want to make an interactive tutorial for my website to guide the user and teach them how my website works and how they do stuff on it. I would like to learn how I can do something like this, but I have no idea where to start. Is it jquery? Ajax? Html5? Plain java script? I'm sorry for the broad question and/or irrelevant tags, but where can I find more information about how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use Twitter Bootstrap: [popovers](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers)

There other cool things in there that can save you from lots of work.

Answer (score 0):

You would need Javascript and CSS, so you can display the notifications and display the next one when the user completes the previous action, and CSS to set the z-index to make the notification appear over the top of the regular content. Also CSS to position the notification.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Jquery UI

go to this url to learn how use it and see the Examples

http://jqueryui.com/